# Populate dropdown in laravel with more than 2 attributes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So far I know how to populate dropdown using Eloquent (and pluck) is this

```
public function create()
{
    $items = Item::all()->pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('admin.item.create', compact('items'));
}
```

And with this

```
{!! Form::select('item_id', $items, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

I can generate this

```
<select name="items" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

But now I want to create something like this

```
<select name="items" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Item 1 - Location</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2 - Location</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3 - Location</option>
</select>
```

I can only use pluck with 2 attributes. But now I want it to display 3 attributes. How do I do that? I'm using Laravel 5.3 by the way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then join two table, item and location and try

Comment: what is your Item fields?

Comment: As what @Komal said, join the two tables (location and item) and concatenate the values then return to view.

Comment: Actually those 3 are from the same table. My Items table has id, name and location as the columns

Comment: Then no need to join tables, just pluck name, id and location also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array like `[1=> "something",2=>"else"]`. So you task is to either iterate the array and edit the values or select the the locations from the database and the use `foreach` or `array_filter`

So something like the following:

```
$items=[];
foreach(Item::all() as $item){
    $items[$item->id] = $item->name . " - " . $item->location->name; // build string to display here
}
```

Edit:

Your comment said location is at the same table so it would look like...

```
$items=[];
foreach(Item::all() as $item){
    $items[$item->id] = $item->name . " - " . $item->location; // build string to display here
}
```

Comment: It works! So now for more than 2 attributes I cannot use pluck(), but I have to use all() instead? Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

Pluck location also

```
public function create()
{
  $items = Item::all()->pluck('name', 'id', 'location');
  return view('admin.item.create', compact('items'));
}
```

Generate like this

```
<select name="items" class="form-control">
  @foreach($items as $item)
    <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }} - {{ $item->location }}</option>
  @endforeach                 
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry but it returns trying to get the property of non-object error. And besides, I think pluck can only return 2 kinds of attributes. Location does not show up even if I dd it. But thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Best way to create list of array is.

```
public function create(){
$items = Item::where('id','<>','')->lists('name', 'id');
return view('admin.item.create', compact('items'));}
```